# Aggregation of daily values to monthly in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I am trying to aggregate a CSV file of daily values to monthly output. The data seems to read in fine but has not inferred as daily frequency. The daily values extend from 1st Jan 2017 to 31st May 2020 but the summing extends to 31st Dec 2020. Possibly the day and month values are getting confused? The summed values are definitely not correct when i check input vs output in Excel.

```
import pandas as pd 

daily_returns = pd.read_csv('C\Path\To\gt_returns.csv', 
                            names=['date', 'return'], sep=',', 
                            index_col=['date'], header=0, parse_dates=['date'])

daily_returns['return'] = daily_returns['return'].str.rstrip('%').astype('float') / 100.0

print(daily_returns)
print()
daily_returns.info()
print()
monthly_returns = daily_returns.resample('M').sum()
monthly_returns.info()
print()

monthly_returns.to_csv('C\Path\To\gt_returns_monthly.csv', sep=',')
```

Here is the output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1247 entries, 2017-01-01 to 2020-05-31
Data columns (total 1 columns):
return    1247 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 19.5 KB

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 48 entries, 2017-01-31 to 2020-12-31
Freq: M
Data columns (total 1 columns):
return    48 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 768.0 bytes
```

Data:

```
Open Time,Return
01/01/2017,0.00%
02/01/2017,0.00%
03/01/2017,0.00%
04/01/2017,2.57%
05/01/2017,-5.94%
06/01/2017,5.38%
07/01/2017,0.79%
08/01/2017,2.23%
09/01/2017,0.44%
10/01/2017,-0.25%
11/01/2017,6.58%
12/01/2017,-0.05%
13/01/2017,-0.15%
14/01/2017,-0.05%
15/01/2017,-0.26%
16/01/2017,1.41%
17/01/2017,4.37%
18/01/2017,-0.83%
19/01/2017,1.31%
20/01/2017,0.70%
21/01/2017,2.99%
22/01/2017,-0.07%
23/01/2017,0.28%
24/01/2017,1.48%
25/01/2017,-0.05%
26/01/2017,-1.96%
27/01/2017,-0.10%
28/01/2017,-0.26%
29/01/2017,0.37%
30/01/2017,0.48%
31/01/2017,3.61%
01/02/2017,0.93%
02/02/2017,1.58%
03/02/2017,0.91%
04/02/2017,2.48%
05/02/2017,-0.89%
06/02/2017,1.19%
07/02/2017,1.76%
08/02/2017,0.61%
09/02/2017,-0.79%
10/02/2017,-0.10%
11/02/2017,0.00%
12/02/2017,0.44%
13/02/2017,0.23%
14/02/2017,-1.05%
15/02/2017,-0.56%
16/02/2017,-0.38%
17/02/2017,0.49%
18/02/2017,0.32%
19/02/2017,-0.06%
20/02/2017,0.57%
21/02/2017,1.69%
22/02/2017,-0.54%
23/02/2017,3.88%
24/02/2017,0.23%
25/02/2017,-2.55%
26/02/2017,0.88%
27/02/2017,-0.05%
28/02/2017,-0.48%
01/03/2017,-1.05%
02/03/2017,6.17%
03/03/2017,1.11%
04/03/2017,-0.66%
05/03/2017,-0.05%
06/03/2017,0.00%
07/03/2017,0.00%
08/03/2017,6.38%
09/03/2017,-0.05%
10/03/2017,4.64%
11/03/2017,8.13%
12/03/2017,6.82%
13/03/2017,10.74%
14/03/2017,-0.37%
15/03/2017,0.21%
16/03/2017,-0.05%
17/03/2017,-8.80%
18/03/2017,-8.80%
19/03/2017,13.80%
20/03/2017,-0.05%
21/03/2017,0.65%
22/03/2017,-1.45%
23/03/2017,-0.49%
24/03/2017,7.73%
25/03/2017,-1.96%
26/03/2017,-1.50%
27/03/2017,-0.05%
28/03/2017,0.11%
29/03/2017,0.00%
30/03/2017,-1.15%
31/03/2017,-0.69%
01/04/2017,1.50%
02/04/2017,-3.17%
03/04/2017,1.75%
04/04/2017,-1.66%
05/04/2017,0.33%
06/04/2017,1.91%
07/04/2017,-1.44%
08/04/2017,-1.61%
09/04/2017,-0.10%
10/04/2017,-0.04%
11/04/2017,-0.54%
12/04/2017,2.62%
13/04/2017,1.31%
14/04/2017,-2.81%
15/04/2017,2.11%
16/04/2017,-0.36%
17/04/2017,-1.88%
18/04/2017,2.16%
19/04/2017,0.17%
20/04/2017,0.23%
21/04/2017,1.41%
22/04/2017,-0.64%
23/04/2017,-0.46%
24/04/2017,-1.05%
25/04/2017,0.62%
26/04/2017,3.80%
27/04/2017,10.84%
28/04/2017,6.55%
29/04/2017,-1.63%
30/04/2017,-0.10%
01/05/2017,-2.58%
02/05/2017,3.46%
03/05/2017,1.96%
04/05/2017,-0.05%
05/05/2017,-0.62%
06/05/2017,-1.16%
07/05/2017,-0.05%
08/05/2017,-1.42%
09/05/2017,1.29%
10/05/2017,1.91%
11/05/2017,1.65%
12/05/2017,-0.10%
13/05/2017,-2.55%
14/05/2017,-1.10%
15/05/2017,2.63%
16/05/2017,-2.71%
17/05/2017,-3.64%
18/05/2017,1.59%
19/05/2017,1.76%
20/05/2017,1.91%
21/05/2017,9.33%
22/05/2017,1.76%
23/05/2017,3.55%
24/05/2017,3.90%
25/05/2017,-2.63%
26/05/2017,-2.60%
27/05/2017,2.07%
28/05/2017,3.12%
29/05/2017,5.15%
30/05/2017,8.44%
31/05/2017,-1.61%
01/06/2017,2.13%
02/06/2017,2.44%
03/06/2017,1.21%
04/06/2017,-0.57%
05/06/2017,3.50%
06/06/2017,6.43%
07/06/2017,-4.59%
08/06/2017,-1.10%
09/06/2017,3.67%
10/06/2017,8.25%
11/06/2017,1.09%
12/06/2017,7.79%
13/06/2017,-1.93%
14/06/2017,4.75%
15/06/2017,0.49%
16/06/2017,-3.25%
17/06/2017,-4.06%
18/06/2017,2.59%
19/06/2017,-2.54%
20/06/2017,-0.10%
21/06/2017,-8.12%
22/06/2017,-1.49%
23/06/2017,0.33%
24/06/2017,3.44%
25/06/2017,-2.57%
26/06/2017,-4.97%
27/06/2017,-0.05%
28/06/2017,4.49%
29/06/2017,3.12%
30/06/2017,-2.37%
01/07/2017,-1.10%
02/07/2017,4.37%
03/07/2017,-0.10%
04/07/2017,2.30%
05/07/2017,-1.47%
06/07/2017,-1.83%
07/07/2017,-0.10%
08/07/2017,-1.05%
09/07/2017,0.94%
10/07/2017,3.20%
11/07/2017,-0.05%
12/07/2017,0.00%
13/07/2017,0.00%
14/07/2017,1.85%
15/07/2017,-6.73%
16/07/2017,-0.05%
17/07/2017,0.00%
18/07/2017,0.00%
19/07/2017,-1.31%
20/07/2017,13.30%
21/07/2017,-3.24%
22/07/2017,3.17%
23/07/2017,-0.05%
24/07/2017,-0.93%
25/07/2017,8.14%
26/07/2017,1.25%
27/07/2017,2.82%
28/07/2017,2.49%
29/07/2017,-1.47%
30/07/2017,-0.05%
31/07/2017,2.45%
01/08/2017,-3.07%
02/08/2017,1.19%
03/08/2017,-1.75%
04/08/2017,0.62%
05/08/2017,12.81%
06/08/2017,-0.10%
07/08/2017,2.39%
08/08/2017,5.51%
09/08/2017,-0.72%
10/08/2017,-0.10%
11/08/2017,0.00%
12/08/2017,1.61%
13/08/2017,4.44%
14/08/2017,3.19%
15/08/2017,-0.05%
16/08/2017,1.38%
17/08/2017,-0.57%
18/08/2017,-0.05%
19/08/2017,-0.48%
20/08/2017,2.04%
21/08/2017,-1.10%
22/08/2017,-0.05%
23/08/2017,-1.34%
24/08/2017,1.37%
25/08/2017,0.70%
26/08/2017,-0.81%
27/08/2017,-0.20%
28/08/2017,-0.11%
29/08/2017,3.52%
30/08/2017,1.38%
31/08/2017,2.31%
01/09/2017,1.88%
02/09/2017,-2.66%
03/09/2017,0.12%
04/09/2017,-4.67%
05/09/2017,-0.05%
06/09/2017,-3.49%
07/09/2017,-0.10%
08/09/2017,-2.96%
09/09/2017,-0.05%
10/09/2017,0.59%
11/09/2017,0.01%
12/09/2017,-2.88%
13/09/2017,2.98%
14/09/2017,-0.05%
15/09/2017,0.00%
16/09/2017,-2.86%
17/09/2017,-0.30%
18/09/2017,4.53%
19/09/2017,-3.39%
20/09/2017,-0.40%
21/09/2017,3.62%
22/09/2017,1.26%
23/09/2017,4.15%
24/09/2017,-0.05%
25/09/2017,5.66%
26/09/2017,-1.60%
27/09/2017,7.79%
28/09/2017,-1.40%
29/09/2017,-5.10%
30/09/2017,4.52%
01/10/2017,-0.10%
02/10/2017,-1.31%
03/10/2017,-0.10%
04/10/2017,-1.19%
05/10/2017,0.95%
06/10/2017,-1.05%
07/10/2017,-0.05%
08/10/2017,2.34%
09/10/2017,1.53%
10/10/2017,-1.09%
11/10/2017,0.35%
12/10/2017,6.31%
13/10/2017,0.98%
14/10/2017,1.90%
15/10/2017,-0.05%
16/10/2017,-1.35%
17/10/2017,4.32%
18/10/2017,1.61%
19/10/2017,-0.32%
20/10/2017,-0.67%
21/10/2017,0.89%
22/10/2017,-1.21%
23/10/2017,-0.54%
24/10/2017,3.56%
25/10/2017,-0.05%
26/10/2017,-0.01%
27/10/2017,-0.89%
28/10/2017,-0.48%
29/10/2017,1.20%
30/10/2017,-0.13%
31/10/2017,2.42%
01/11/2017,-0.10%
02/11/2017,1.92%
03/11/2017,0.68%
04/11/2017,-1.09%
05/11/2017,-0.42%
06/11/2017,-2.60%
07/11/2017,-1.14%
08/11/2017,-0.62%
09/11/2017,0.92%
10/11/2017,-3.03%
11/11/2017,-0.05%
12/11/2017,0.00%
13/11/2017,1.22%
14/11/2017,3.61%
15/11/2017,-0.64%
16/11/2017,4.14%
17/11/2017,-1.01%
18/11/2017,0.36%
19/11/2017,-0.05%
20/11/2017,1.82%
21/11/2017,-3.27%
22/11/2017,2.51%
23/11/2017,-1.23%
24/11/2017,7.80%
25/11/2017,-1.82%
26/11/2017,-0.10%
27/11/2017,0.97%
28/11/2017,0.58%
29/11/2017,-3.70%
30/11/2017,-0.10%
01/12/2017,0.00%
02/12/2017,0.45%
03/12/2017,-0.05%
04/12/2017,1.06%
05/12/2017,0.47%
06/12/2017,12.42%
07/12/2017,11.20%
08/12/2017,2.24%
09/12/2017,-4.60%
10/12/2017,-4.03%
11/12/2017,9.52%
12/12/2017,-0.82%
13/12/2017,5.98%
14/12/2017,-1.25%
15/12/2017,-1.87%
16/12/2017,-0.10%
17/12/2017,0.00%
18/12/2017,-0.04%
19/12/2017,4.98%
20/12/2017,-5.21%
21/12/2017,-0.05%
22/12/2017,9.31%
23/12/2017,-0.05%
24/12/2017,2.03%
25/12/2017,-4.39%
26/12/2017,9.51%
27/12/2017,-1.40%
28/12/2017,-4.53%
29/12/2017,-2.13%
30/12/2017,-3.67%
31/12/2017,-0.05%
01/01/2018,1.18%
02/01/2018,11.33%
03/01/2018,5.44%
04/01/2018,0.79%
05/01/2018,7.34%
06/01/2018,0.27%
07/01/2018,-2.69%
08/01/2018,-5.58%
09/01/2018,6.96%
10/01/2018,-3.51%
11/01/2018,5.55%
12/01/2018,1.79%
13/01/2018,-2.65%
14/01/2018,-1.58%
15/01/2018,0.14%
16/01/2018,20.26%
17/01/2018,-0.10%
18/01/2018,0.00%
19/01/2018,0.00%
20/01/2018,0.00%
21/01/2018,0.00%
22/01/2018,-4.07%
23/01/2018,-0.80%
24/01/2018,-3.83%
25/01/2018,-0.92%
26/01/2018,-0.36%
27/01/2018,0.56%
28/01/2018,-0.10%
29/01/2018,-6.12%
30/01/2018,4.35%
31/01/2018,-0.05%
01/02/2018,3.59%
02/02/2018,-0.10%
03/02/2018,0.00%
04/02/2018,0.00%
05/02/2018,-7.05%
06/02/2018,-0.10%
07/02/2018,-5.48%
08/02/2018,-0.10%
09/02/2018,11.78%
10/02/2018,-2.34%
11/02/2018,5.03%
12/02/2018,3.68%
13/02/2018,-2.09%
14/02/2018,5.33%
15/02/2018,3.16%
16/02/2018,1.56%
17/02/2018,-0.10%
18/02/2018,0.00%
19/02/2018,3.66%
20/02/2018,0.22%
21/02/2018,-3.60%
22/02/2018,-0.10%
23/02/2018,1.58%
24/02/2018,-3.78%
25/02/2018,-0.05%
26/02/2018,0.13%
27/02/2018,0.07%
28/02/2018,-1.25%
01/03/2018,-0.05%
02/03/2018,-0.38%
03/03/2018,-0.10%
04/03/2018,0.57%
05/03/2018,-0.05%
06/03/2018,3.17%
07/03/2018,-0.05%
08/03/2018,0.00%
09/03/2018,0.00%
10/03/2018,2.93%
11/03/2018,2.67%
12/03/2018,-2.16%
13/03/2018,-1.00%
14/03/2018,11.14%
15/03/2018,-0.10%
16/03/2018,-0.85%
17/03/2018,2.53%
18/03/2018,-1.02%
19/03/2018,1.70%
20/03/2018,1.76%
21/03/2018,-0.10%
22/03/2018,0.50%
23/03/2018,-0.34%
24/03/2018,0.08%
25/03/2018,-1.70%
26/03/2018,-1.13%
27/03/2018,-0.10%
28/03/2018,0.94%
29/03/2018,12.27%
30/03/2018,-0.10%
31/03/2018,-1.82%
01/04/2018,-0.05%
02/04/2018,-0.15%
03/04/2018,2.42%
04/04/2018,-3.09%
05/04/2018,-0.05%
06/04/2018,0.00%
07/04/2018,-2.45%
08/04/2018,1.92%
09/04/2018,-0.05%
10/04/2018,1.53%
11/04/2018,2.32%
12/04/2018,14.67%
13/04/2018,-0.34%
14/04/2018,1.54%
15/04/2018,-0.10%
16/04/2018,-3.94%
17/04/2018,0.97%
18/04/2018,-2.10%
19/04/2018,4.44%
20/04/2018,7.81%
21/04/2018,-0.66%
22/04/2018,0.61%
23/04/2018,-0.10%
24/04/2018,8.12%
25/04/2018,-7.85%
26/04/2018,-0.10%
27/04/2018,0.00%
28/04/2018,-2.96%
29/04/2018,0.76%
30/04/2018,0.43%
01/05/2018,-0.14%
02/05/2018,2.05%
03/05/2018,-2.10%
04/05/2018,0.06%
05/05/2018,2.08%
06/05/2018,-0.05%
07/05/2018,-3.29%
08/05/2018,-0.05%
09/05/2018,-1.28%
10/05/2018,3.60%
11/05/2018,3.10%
12/05/2018,-0.05%
13/05/2018,0.00%
14/05/2018,0.00%
15/05/2018,0.00%
16/05/2018,0.58%
17/05/2018,4.47%
18/05/2018,-2.10%
19/05/2018,-1.01%
20/05/2018,1.22%
21/05/2018,-2.26%
22/05/2018,6.21%
23/05/2018,2.93%
24/05/2018,-0.05%
25/05/2018,2.06%
26/05/2018,-0.99%
27/05/2018,1.10%
28/05/2018,6.80%
29/05/2018,-0.10%
30/05/2018,-0.62%
31/05/2018,0.74%
01/06/2018,0.00%
02/06/2018,1.76%
03/06/2018,0.44%
04/06/2018,-4.02%
05/06/2018,-2.10%
06/06/2018,0.07%
07/06/2018,-0.05%
08/06/2018,0.52%
09/06/2018,0.20%
10/06/2018,10.55%
11/06/2018,-0.10%
12/06/2018,-6.23%
13/06/2018,-0.10%
14/06/2018,0.00%
15/06/2018,0.00%
16/06/2018,0.69%
17/06/2018,-0.05%
18/06/2018,1.99%
19/06/2018,2.10%
20/06/2018,-0.19%
21/06/2018,-0.05%
22/06/2018,3.49%
23/06/2018,-0.10%
24/06/2018,1.96%
25/06/2018,-0.05%
26/06/2018,1.65%
27/06/2018,-0.84%
28/06/2018,-4.81%
29/06/2018,-1.10%
30/06/2018,1.45%
01/07/2018,-0.53%
02/07/2018,-0.10%
03/07/2018,-2.38%
04/07/2018,1.16%
05/07/2018,-0.10%
06/07/2018,-0.99%
07/07/2018,-0.10%
08/07/2018,0.07%
09/07/2018,-1.97%
10/07/2018,6.70%
11/07/2018,-0.10%
12/07/2018,0.95%
13/07/2018,0.05%
14/07/2018,-0.40%
15/07/2018,-2.10%
16/07/2018,3.04%
17/07/2018,6.49%
18/07/2018,-1.50%
19/07/2018,-0.56%
20/07/2018,-0.91%
21/07/2018,-1.62%
22/07/2018,-1.13%
23/07/2018,2.11%
24/07/2018,4.38%
25/07/2018,-2.12%
26/07/2018,-2.57%
27/07/2018,2.50%
28/07/2018,0.14%
29/07/2018,-0.39%
30/07/2018,0.76%
31/07/2018,-0.10%
01/08/2018,0.00%
02/08/2018,0.00%
03/08/2018,0.00%
04/08/2018,1.18%
05/08/2018,-0.35%
06/08/2018,1.07%
07/08/2018,2.29%
08/08/2018,-0.10%
09/08/2018,0.00%
10/08/2018,7.19%
11/08/2018,-0.10%
12/08/2018,0.56%
13/08/2018,5.26%
14/08/2018,0.37%
15/08/2018,-1.05%
16/08/2018,-0.05%
17/08/2018,0.00%
18/08/2018,-6.78%
19/08/2018,0.85%
20/08/2018,-0.05%
21/08/2018,-2.56%
22/08/2018,-2.48%
23/08/2018,-1.10%
24/08/2018,-0.05%
25/08/2018,0.34%
26/08/2018,-0.05%
27/08/2018,-1.05%
28/08/2018,2.41%
29/08/2018,-1.51%
30/08/2018,-2.88%
31/08/2018,-0.25%
01/09/2018,-1.10%
02/09/2018,0.61%
03/09/2018,-0.05%
04/09/2018,1.22%
05/09/2018,7.40%
06/09/2018,-0.10%
07/09/2018,3.10%
08/09/2018,4.30%
09/09/2018,-0.98%
10/09/2018,-2.08%
11/09/2018,2.99%
12/09/2018,-0.45%
13/09/2018,1.07%
14/09/2018,-0.57%
15/09/2018,3.28%
16/09/2018,-0.10%
17/09/2018,-2.02%
18/09/2018,-1.76%
19/09/2018,-1.10%
20/09/2018,-0.05%
21/09/2018,7.25%
22/09/2018,-1.62%
23/09/2018,-0.10%
24/09/2018,0.00%
25/09/2018,0.97%
26/09/2018,-0.05%
27/09/2018,0.00%
28/09/2018,-0.46%
29/09/2018,-1.64%
30/09/2018,-0.10%
01/10/2018,0.00%
02/10/2018,1.83%
03/10/2018,-1.07%
04/10/2018,-1.10%
05/10/2018,-1.05%
06/10/2018,-0.41%
07/10/2018,0.27%
08/10/2018,1.29%
09/10/2018,-0.47%
10/10/2018,0.36%
11/10/2018,10.61%
12/10/2018,-0.10%
13/10/2018,-1.15%
14/10/2018,-0.15%
15/10/2018,4.31%
16/10/2018,0.16%
17/10/2018,-0.10%
18/10/2018,0.00%
19/10/2018,0.00%
20/10/2018,0.15%
21/10/2018,-0.06%
22/10/2018,-0.05%
23/10/2018,0.31%
24/10/2018,0.07%
25/10/2018,0.58%
26/10/2018,-0.13%
27/10/2018,0.25%
28/10/2018,0.12%
29/10/2018,-0.89%
30/10/2018,-0.10%
31/10/2018,0.00%
01/11/2018,0.00%
02/11/2018,0.00%
03/11/2018,-0.97%
04/11/2018,-0.10%
05/11/2018,-0.57%
06/11/2018,2.78%
07/11/2018,0.41%
08/11/2018,-2.23%
09/11/2018,0.32%
10/11/2018,0.49%
11/11/2018,0.07%
12/11/2018,-0.04%
13/11/2018,0.65%
14/11/2018,5.29%
15/11/2018,-0.05%
16/11/2018,0.00%
17/11/2018,0.00%
18/11/2018,-0.59%
19/11/2018,-2.60%
20/11/2018,-0.05%
21/11/2018,0.00%
22/11/2018,0.00%
23/11/2018,-0.04%
24/11/2018,3.25%
25/11/2018,-0.10%
26/11/2018,6.00%
27/11/2018,-0.39%
28/11/2018,3.19%
29/11/2018,-1.74%
30/11/2018,-3.22%
01/12/2018,1.82%
02/12/2018,-0.05%
03/12/2018,0.00%
04/12/2018,-1.05%
05/12/2018,5.54%
06/12/2018,-1.10%
07/12/2018,-0.05%
08/12/2018,-1.64%
09/12/2018,-1.69%
10/12/2018,-0.05%
11/12/2018,0.71%
12/12/2018,-0.16%
13/12/2018,-0.10%
14/12/2018,2.54%
15/12/2018,-0.01%
16/12/2018,-0.05%
17/12/2018,5.47%
18/12/2018,5.39%
19/12/2018,-0.70%
20/12/2018,13.04%
21/12/2018,-5.39%
22/12/2018,-0.10%
23/12/2018,0.00%
24/12/2018,4.38%
25/12/2018,-5.94%
26/12/2018,1.11%
27/12/2018,-3.12%
28/12/2018,-3.68%
29/12/2018,-1.04%
30/12/2018,-1.10%
31/12/2018,-0.05%
01/01/2019,-1.05%
02/01/2019,-0.05%
03/01/2019,-3.17%
04/01/2019,1.50%
05/01/2019,0.56%
06/01/2019,-0.10%
07/01/2019,-0.20%
08/01/2019,0.28%
09/01/2019,-0.90%
10/01/2019,7.77%
11/01/2019,-0.05%
12/01/2019,0.00%
13/01/2019,5.11%
14/01/2019,-3.90%
15/01/2019,-0.10%
16/01/2019,0.00%
17/01/2019,0.29%
18/01/2019,0.87%
19/01/2019,-1.17%
20/01/2019,-0.05%
21/01/2019,-0.22%
22/01/2019,-0.05%
23/01/2019,0.00%
24/01/2019,-0.03%
25/01/2019,0.44%
26/01/2019,-1.10%
27/01/2019,-1.53%
28/01/2019,-0.05%
29/01/2019,0.00%
30/01/2019,0.00%
31/01/2019,0.00%
01/02/2019,-0.46%
02/02/2019,1.63%
03/02/2019,-0.05%
04/02/2019,0.00%
05/02/2019,-0.03%
06/02/2019,-3.60%
07/02/2019,-0.14%
08/02/2019,-1.05%
09/02/2019,-0.09%
10/02/2019,-0.10%
11/02/2019,-1.74%
12/02/2019,-0.78%
13/02/2019,-0.37%
14/02/2019,-0.38%
15/02/2019,-1.22%
16/02/2019,-1.27%
17/02/2019,-0.10%
18/02/2019,7.51%
19/02/2019,-0.65%
20/02/2019,0.74%
21/02/2019,-0.05%
22/02/2019,-0.36%
23/02/2019,3.44%
24/02/2019,-6.41%
25/02/2019,-0.10%
26/02/2019,-0.94%
27/02/2019,0.12%
28/02/2019,-0.06%
01/03/2019,-0.11%
02/03/2019,0.97%
03/03/2019,0.74%
04/03/2019,3.06%
05/03/2019,-0.10%
06/03/2019,0.20%
07/03/2019,-0.26%
08/03/2019,0.94%
09/03/2019,-1.10%
10/03/2019,-0.43%
11/03/2019,-1.62%
12/03/2019,-0.49%
13/03/2019,0.45%
14/03/2019,-1.29%
15/03/2019,0.95%
16/03/2019,2.54%
17/03/2019,-1.11%
18/03/2019,-0.10%
19/03/2019,-0.80%
20/03/2019,0.19%
21/03/2019,-3.32%
22/03/2019,-0.23%
23/03/2019,-0.58%
24/03/2019,0.07%
25/03/2019,-0.12%
26/03/2019,-0.10%
27/03/2019,3.00%
28/03/2019,-0.70%
29/03/2019,-1.10%
30/03/2019,-0.38%
31/03/2019,-0.43%
01/04/2019,-0.05%
02/04/2019,8.55%
03/04/2019,-0.30%
04/04/2019,-1.16%
05/04/2019,-0.10%
06/04/2019,0.34%
07/04/2019,3.83%
08/04/2019,-0.10%
09/04/2019,-2.08%
10/04/2019,0.67%
11/04/2019,-0.05%
12/04/2019,0.00%
13/04/2019,-0.01%
14/04/2019,-2.28%
15/04/2019,0.99%
16/04/2019,-0.05%
17/04/2019,0.00%
18/04/2019,0.00%
19/04/2019,-0.30%
20/04/2019,0.38%
21/04/2019,-1.29%
22/04/2019,0.57%
23/04/2019,-0.40%
24/04/2019,-0.81%
25/04/2019,1.70%
26/04/2019,-0.05%
27/04/2019,-1.27%
28/04/2019,-0.26%
29/04/2019,1.47%
30/04/2019,-1.10%
01/05/2019,-0.07%
02/05/2019,-0.10%
03/05/2019,4.38%
04/05/2019,-0.81%
05/05/2019,-0.66%
06/05/2019,3.00%
07/05/2019,-1.10%
08/05/2019,1.65%
09/05/2019,-0.10%
10/05/2019,0.00%
11/05/2019,10.41%
12/05/2019,-1.32%
13/05/2019,7.96%
14/05/2019,0.96%
15/05/2019,7.22%
16/05/2019,1.35%
17/05/2019,-1.16%
18/05/2019,-0.10%
19/05/2019,-1.44%
20/05/2019,-1.86%
21/05/2019,-0.05%
22/05/2019,0.38%
23/05/2019,-1.59%
24/05/2019,-0.27%
25/05/2019,-0.77%
26/05/2019,-1.10%
27/05/2019,1.82%
28/05/2019,-0.14%
29/05/2019,-0.10%
30/05/2019,-2.15%
31/05/2019,-0.10%
01/06/2019,0.01%
02/06/2019,-2.21%
03/06/2019,3.48%
04/06/2019,1.70%
05/06/2019,-0.05%
06/06/2019,-1.05%
07/06/2019,-1.05%
08/06/2019,1.06%
09/06/2019,0.79%
10/06/2019,1.27%
11/06/2019,-0.66%
12/06/2019,1.54%
13/06/2019,-0.73%
14/06/2019,4.16%
15/06/2019,1.94%
16/06/2019,0.80%
17/06/2019,3.03%
18/06/2019,-2.80%
19/06/2019,-0.10%
20/06/2019,0.52%
21/06/2019,3.28%
22/06/2019,5.55%
23/06/2019,0.46%
24/06/2019,-0.10%
25/06/2019,4.42%
26/06/2019,8.70%
27/06/2019,-8.78%
28/06/2019,-2.71%
29/06/2019,-0.05%
30/06/2019,4.36%
01/07/2019,0.60%
02/07/2019,0.56%
03/07/2019,0.20%
04/07/2019,-0.10%
05/07/2019,-2.22%
06/07/2019,-2.20%
07/07/2019,-1.10%
08/07/2019,1.09%
09/07/2019,0.47%
10/07/2019,-5.27%
11/07/2019,3.01%
12/07/2019,-1.44%
13/07/2019,1.71%
14/07/2019,13.14%
15/07/2019,3.12%
16/07/2019,6.35%
17/07/2019,-0.05%
18/07/2019,4.91%
19/07/2019,-1.21%
20/07/2019,1.69%
21/07/2019,-0.05%
22/07/2019,0.00%
23/07/2019,3.36%
24/07/2019,-0.10%
25/07/2019,0.00%
26/07/2019,-0.33%
27/07/2019,-2.10%
28/07/2019,0.89%
29/07/2019,-0.05%
30/07/2019,-0.36%
31/07/2019,-2.10%
01/08/2019,1.31%
02/08/2019,0.72%
03/08/2019,0.34%
04/08/2019,-0.10%
05/08/2019,4.07%
06/08/2019,-3.07%
07/08/2019,2.11%
08/08/2019,-0.94%
09/08/2019,2.30%
10/08/2019,1.30%
11/08/2019,1.26%
12/08/2019,-0.49%
13/08/2019,2.16%
14/08/2019,-0.05%
15/08/2019,0.00%
16/08/2019,-1.05%
17/08/2019,-0.05%
18/08/2019,2.70%
19/08/2019,2.00%
20/08/2019,-2.16%
21/08/2019,2.72%
22/08/2019,-1.10%
23/08/2019,0.86%
24/08/2019,-0.05%
25/08/2019,-0.09%
26/08/2019,-2.10%
27/08/2019,-0.62%
28/08/2019,5.97%
29/08/2019,-2.60%
30/08/2019,-0.05%
31/08/2019,0.80%
01/09/2019,-0.10%
02/09/2019,2.09%
03/09/2019,1.48%
04/09/2019,-1.35%
05/09/2019,-0.29%
06/09/2019,-2.10%
07/09/2019,-1.10%
08/09/2019,0.90%
09/09/2019,-0.18%
10/09/2019,-1.05%
11/09/2019,0.43%
12/09/2019,-0.05%
13/09/2019,-0.40%
14/09/2019,1.88%
15/09/2019,0.03%
16/09/2019,1.92%
17/09/2019,2.64%
18/09/2019,0.57%
19/09/2019,1.91%
20/09/2019,-0.55%
21/09/2019,-0.05%
22/09/2019,-1.21%
23/09/2019,1.58%
24/09/2019,8.71%
25/09/2019,-0.05%
26/09/2019,0.00%
27/09/2019,0.00%
28/09/2019,0.08%
29/09/2019,-1.32%
30/09/2019,4.91%
01/10/2019,-1.42%
02/10/2019,-0.64%
03/10/2019,-0.10%
04/10/2019,0.67%
05/10/2019,-0.47%
06/10/2019,-0.10%
07/10/2019,-1.05%
08/10/2019,-0.07%
09/10/2019,5.73%
10/10/2019,-0.40%
11/10/2019,-0.10%
12/10/2019,-0.85%
13/10/2019,-1.10%
14/10/2019,-1.05%
15/10/2019,-1.23%
16/10/2019,2.54%
17/10/2019,-0.10%
18/10/2019,1.20%
19/10/2019,-0.11%
20/10/2019,0.58%
21/10/2019,-0.61%
22/10/2019,-1.13%
23/10/2019,3.35%
24/10/2019,-0.05%
25/10/2019,0.00%
26/10/2019,2.67%
27/10/2019,2.81%
28/10/2019,-0.10%
29/10/2019,1.20%
30/10/2019,-3.37%
31/10/2019,0.08%
01/11/2019,-0.78%
02/11/2019,-0.33%
03/11/2019,0.32%
04/11/2019,-2.10%
05/11/2019,0.15%
06/11/2019,0.39%
07/11/2019,-0.51%
08/11/2019,-0.10%
09/11/2019,0.26%
10/11/2019,-2.10%
11/11/2019,-1.20%
12/11/2019,0.57%
13/11/2019,0.27%
14/11/2019,0.64%
15/11/2019,2.29%
16/11/2019,-0.10%
17/11/2019,-1.17%
18/11/2019,0.23%
19/11/2019,-0.10%
20/11/2019,0.00%
21/11/2019,3.87%
22/11/2019,-0.05%
23/11/2019,0.00%
24/11/2019,0.00%
25/11/2019,-4.37%
26/11/2019,-0.28%
27/11/2019,-0.10%
28/11/2019,-1.32%
29/11/2019,-1.26%
30/11/2019,-1.14%
01/12/2019,-0.05%
02/12/2019,-1.44%
03/12/2019,-0.10%
04/12/2019,-1.05%
05/12/2019,0.84%
06/12/2019,1.01%
07/12/2019,-0.70%
08/12/2019,-0.10%
09/12/2019,0.00%
10/12/2019,1.30%
11/12/2019,0.84%
12/12/2019,-0.43%
13/12/2019,-0.47%
14/12/2019,-1.44%
15/12/2019,-0.49%
16/12/2019,1.59%
17/12/2019,-0.05%
18/12/2019,0.00%
19/12/2019,-0.93%
20/12/2019,-0.05%
21/12/2019,-0.43%
22/12/2019,4.54%
23/12/2019,-2.85%
24/12/2019,-0.50%
25/12/2019,0.99%
26/12/2019,-2.10%
27/12/2019,-0.42%
28/12/2019,-0.05%
29/12/2019,0.44%
30/12/2019,-2.04%
31/12/2019,-0.67%
01/01/2020,-1.09%
02/01/2020,1.58%
03/01/2020,-1.10%
04/01/2020,-0.14%
05/01/2020,-0.10%
06/01/2020,-1.05%
07/01/2020,1.88%
08/01/2020,-1.28%
09/01/2020,-1.53%
10/01/2020,1.38%
11/01/2020,-1.13%
12/01/2020,1.03%
13/01/2020,-0.05%
14/01/2020,4.26%
15/01/2020,0.24%
16/01/2020,-1.23%
17/01/2020,-0.10%
18/01/2020,1.21%
19/01/2020,-2.70%
20/01/2020,0.02%
21/01/2020,-1.64%
22/01/2020,0.73%
23/01/2020,3.16%
24/01/2020,-0.10%
25/01/2020,-0.63%
26/01/2020,-2.10%
27/01/2020,-0.10%
28/01/2020,4.15%
29/01/2020,-0.93%
30/01/2020,1.09%
31/01/2020,-2.17%
01/02/2020,-0.10%
02/02/2020,-0.33%
03/02/2020,-0.77%
04/02/2020,-0.26%
05/02/2020,3.94%
06/02/2020,3.09%
07/02/2020,2.59%
08/02/2020,-0.11%
09/02/2020,1.22%
10/02/2020,-1.58%
11/02/2020,-2.10%
12/02/2020,6.44%
13/02/2020,0.02%
14/02/2020,3.09%
15/02/2020,-0.05%
16/02/2020,-1.62%
17/02/2020,0.47%
18/02/2020,2.71%
19/02/2020,-0.05%
20/02/2020,0.17%
21/02/2020,-1.77%
22/02/2020,0.83%
23/02/2020,-2.38%
24/02/2020,-4.41%
25/02/2020,5.11%
26/02/2020,2.80%
27/02/2020,-0.05%
28/02/2020,0.86%
29/02/2020,0.92%
01/03/2020,-2.70%
02/03/2020,-2.40%
03/03/2020,-1.02%
04/03/2020,-0.05%
05/03/2020,-2.10%
06/03/2020,3.84%
07/03/2020,-1.61%
08/03/2020,-2.60%
09/03/2020,-0.05%
10/03/2020,0.47%
11/03/2020,1.21%
12/03/2020,42.05%
13/03/2020,-0.10%
14/03/2020,7.84%
15/03/2020,-7.10%
16/03/2020,-3.25%
17/03/2020,-3.55%
18/03/2020,-1.15%
19/03/2020,-0.05%
20/03/2020,-0.76%
21/03/2020,-0.48%
22/03/2020,-0.10%
23/03/2020,11.06%
24/03/2020,3.06%
25/03/2020,-0.89%
26/03/2020,-0.05%
27/03/2020,0.00%
28/03/2020,0.91%
29/03/2020,-5.26%
30/03/2020,-2.10%
31/03/2020,-0.10%
01/04/2020,1.07%
02/04/2020,-0.05%
03/04/2020,-0.53%
04/04/2020,0.94%
05/04/2020,-0.05%
06/04/2020,0.00%
07/04/2020,-2.96%
08/04/2020,3.71%
09/04/2020,-0.10%
10/04/2020,-7.01%
11/04/2020,-0.31%
12/04/2020,-1.19%
13/04/2020,1.15%
14/04/2020,-0.10%
15/04/2020,3.51%
16/04/2020,-2.10%
17/04/2020,-1.19%
18/04/2020,4.84%
19/04/2020,-0.05%
20/04/2020,-3.16%
21/04/2020,-1.21%
22/04/2020,-1.21%
23/04/2020,1.33%
24/04/2020,0.61%
25/04/2020,-0.10%
26/04/2020,0.00%
27/04/2020,0.17%
28/04/2020,-0.30%
29/04/2020,-1.10%
30/04/2020,-3.21%
01/05/2020,1.15%
02/05/2020,-0.05%
03/05/2020,-0.99%
04/05/2020,-2.65%
05/05/2020,-1.10%
06/05/2020,-0.48%
07/05/2020,3.56%
08/05/2020,-0.98%
09/05/2020,1.23%
10/05/2020,-5.10%
11/05/2020,-0.10%
12/05/2020,1.03%
13/05/2020,-3.37%
14/05/2020,-0.10%
15/05/2020,-5.28%
16/05/2020,1.78%
17/05/2020,1.54%
18/05/2020,2.14%
19/05/2020,0.14%
20/05/2020,1.20%
21/05/2020,-0.22%
22/05/2020,-0.10%
23/05/2020,-0.10%
24/05/2020,2.50%
25/05/2020,-0.12%
26/05/2020,0.47%
27/05/2020,-2.10%
28/05/2020,4.68%
29/05/2020,-0.67%
30/05/2020,5.16%
31/05/2020,-2.48%
```

Comment: without your data we can't test code and see problem.

Comment: Can you share your output for daily_returns and monthly_returns?

Comment: Good point thanks! Date is added above. Maybe there is a better way to attach it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your date times begin with day first format, `d-m-y`, you must specify the argument `dayfirst` in [**`read.csv`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Default is U.S. date format of month-first and Excel aligns to region/time setting of machine.

```
daily_returns = pd.read_csv('C\Path\To\gt_returns.csv', 
                        names=['date', 'return'], sep=',', 
                        index_col=['date'], header=0, 
                        parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)
...

monthly_returns = daily_returns.resample('M').sum()
monthly_returns.head()
#             Return
# Open Time         
# 2017-01-31  0.2502
# 2017-02-28  0.1074
# 2017-03-31  0.3932
# 2017-04-30  0.1982
# 2017-05-31  0.3266
```